# How to Root volume partition without losing the data

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, partition, ext4, swap

We have this scenario : I to increase the disk space of one of our VM,

Disk details :

```
root@Test-01:~# blkid
/dev/vda2: UUID="0eae0eb4-92ed-45ec-aa99-6d606f17e70a" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="06cf22a2-02"
/dev/vda1: UUID="b5e223df-9f41-4e4c-aa8d-e4529fa28424" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="06cf22a2-01"


root@Test-01:~# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
vda    254:0    0  150G  0 disk
├─vda1 254:1    0   46G  0 part /
└─vda2 254:2    0  104G  0 part [SWAP]
As its a Not LVM I have tried the below , but its wont work

parted /dev/vda resizepart 1 100%

resize2fs /dev/vda1

root@Test-01:~# parted /dev/vda print free
Model: Virtio Block Device (virtblk)
Disk /dev/vda: 161GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
        1024B   1049kB  1048kB           Free Space
 1      1049kB  49.4GB  49.4GB  primary  ext4
 2      49.4GB  161GB   112GB   primary  linux-swap(v1)
```

we need the swap to go in the last in memory block, swap is in between

we have 112GB primary Linux-swap(v1)

now we want to increase first partition end block to 156 instead of 49.4 gb

now we want to decrease 2nd partition start block to 156 instead of 49.4 gb

we want to increase the root volum with safe option without loosing any data ,

Is Performing the resize operation with parted alone is risky and could lead to data loss? So below doesn't look like safe for me.

```
sudo parted /dev/vda resizepart 1 100%
sudo parted /dev/vda move 2 100%
```

This is a virtual machine not a physical machine we are not a not able to use usb or cd drive there , its a Linux Debian machine .

what is the best way to perform this without losing the root volume data , any help would be apricated .

Comment: not sure how the parted commands you proposed will do anything - since there is no room for part 1 to grow

Comment: Are you certain that this is the machine you want to continue with? Possibly it has been setup with use cases in mind that are *wildly* different from the swap size you are aiming for now, or some severe disregard of the release notes for the OS installed. Both might cause trouble for its future maintenance in places yet to be revealed.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to not lose the root volume data is to use this excuse to do a **complete backup restoration, on a freshly setup, unambiguously separate machine** and the just switch over to that one when it turns out your backups are fine.

---

If you actually wanted to work on a live machine... just order the steps according to their dependencies.

Online add/remove of partition is supported. Online ext filesystem growing is supported. Partition table reloading is not fully supported for active filesystems, but costs only a reboot.

0. verify your backup restoration routine
1. comment out swap entry in fstab
2. systemctl reload
3. swapoff
4. remove swap partition
5. extend root partition into now unused space
6. reboot as needed
7. resize2fs /dev/vda1
8. recreate swap partition (at new position)
9. mkswap /dev/vda2
10. update / re-enable swap entry in fstab
11. reboot once more to verify automatic swap activation work again